# Calculating word frequency for multi-words in R?

Tags: r, tm, word-frequency

I'm trying to compute the frequency of multi-words in a given text. For instance, consider the text: "Environmental Research Environmental Research Environmental Research study science energy, economics, agriculture, ecology, and biology". And then I want the number of times the combined words "environmental research" occurs in the text. Here is the code that I've tried.

```
library(tm)
#Reading the data
text = readLines(file.choose())
text1 = Corpus(VectorSource(text))

#Cleaning the data
text1 = tm_map(text1, content_transformer(tolower))
text1 = tm_map(text1, removePunctuation)
text1 = tm_map(text1, removeNumbers)
text1 = tm_map(text1, stripWhitespace)
text1 = tm_map(text1, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#Making a document matrix
dtm = TermDocumentMatrix(text1)
m11 = as.matrix(text1)
freq11 = sort(rowSums(m11), decreasing=TRUE)
d11 = data.frame(word=names(freq11), freq=freq11)
head(d11,9)
```

This code, however, produces the frequency of each word separately. Instead, how do I obtain the number of times "environmental research" occurs together in the text? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of multiwords already and you want to compute their frequency in a text, you can use `str_extract_all`:

```
text <- "Environmental Research Environmental Research Environmental Research study science energy, economics, agriculture, ecology, and biology"

library(stringr)
str_extract_all(text, "[Ee]nvironmental [Rr]esearch")
[[1]]
[1] "Environmental Research" "Environmental Research" "Environmental Research"
```

If you want to know how often the multiword occurs you can do this:

```
length(unlist(str_extract_all(text, "[Ee]nvironmental [Rr]esearch")))
[1] 3
```

If you're interested in extracting all multiwords at once you can proceed like this:

First define a vector with all multiwords:

```
multiwords <- c("[Ee]nvironmental [Rr]esearch", "study science energy")
```

Then use `paste0` to collapse them into a single string of alternative patterns and use `str_extract_all` on that string:

```
str_extract_all(text, paste0(multiwords, collapse = "|"))
[[1]]
[1] "Environmental Research" "Environmental Research" "Environmental Research" "study science energy"
```

To get the frequencies of the multiwords you can use `table`:

```
table(str_extract_all(text, paste0(multiwords, collapse = "|")))

Environmental Research   study science energy 
                     3                      1
```

Comment: @ Chris Ruehlemann Can I ask you one more question? Basically, I have many multi-words. When I try `str_extract_all(global, paste0(multiwords, collapse = "|"))` it gives me an error which says: `Error in stri_extract_all_regex(string, pattern, simplify = simplify,  : Missing closing bracket on a bracket expression. U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET)`. Would you kindly guide me to fix the problem, please? Tnxs!

Comment: Difficult to judge from here; as far as I can see the only difference between my code and yours is that you subbed `text`for `global`, right? In that piece of code I can't see why there's a bracket missing. If you can give me more access to your data I might be able to help you better. But perhaps you can try and figure out the solution yourself. I'm pretty sure it's just a tiny bit that's missing or incorrect in your code.

Comment: I got my error. Tnx! I have one more question. Let's consider the following scenario. `txt1<-"Environmental Research Environmental Research Nature"` and `txt2 <-"Environ. Res. Environ. Res. Nat."`. My interest is to extract words in txt1 or txt2 based on the condition. By the way, txt2 is the abbreviated form of tx1. To make it clear, if full name is found in the text the code will extract txt1. If the abbreviated form is found in the text, then the code will extract txt2. How I can combine these two conditions?

Comment: You could define these patterns as additional alternative patterns, e.g., thus: `multiwords <- c("Environmental Research", "Environ. Res.", "Environmental Research Nature", "Environ. Res. Nat.")`. Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate for your swift reply!

Comment: @ Chris Ruehlemann Consider the following situation. `mydata<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
     text=c("This is text mining exercise","Text analysis is bit confusing",
   "Hint on this text analysis?"))` and `multiwords<-c("text","analysis","bit confusing")`. And then the code:`txt = freq = list()
for(i in 1:length(mydata$id)){
 txt[i]<-str_extract_all(mydata[i,], paste0(multiwords,collapse = "|"))
 freq[i]<-table(txt[i])
}` gives me an error which says `replacement has length zero` and `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: That's a statement. What is the question? Or, what do you want to achieve with the for loop?

Comment: I need the for loop to generate the frequency table of those multiwords at each iteration. Of course, all mutiwords are not necessarily appear at each iteration.

Comment: I think it will be best if you post this as a new question to SO. This way you'll have a much better chance of getting good answers. You'll also have more space to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Ok. I will post it now. Tnx!